# How to ask for travelling recommendations in German

Tags: question

```
I habe keine Idee überhaupt (über heute Abend).
Kann ich bitte noch mal fragen für deine Empfehlung?
Ich möchte etwas mit viel spaß machen, aber nicht bis zu spät, und mit nicht zu viel trinken, weil Morgen ist meinen letzten Tag hier.
Freundlich Grüße,
O.
```

This is a respond to a local that asked me what am I up to.
I would much appreciate any grammatical of syntax corrections.

Comment: You will be understood.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's proofreading which is off-topic here.

Comment: I don't think it is proofreading. He tried. Now he wants to tell him what is wrong and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I habe keine Idee überhaupt (über heute Abend).

This would sound better, if you say:

> **Ich** habe überhaupt keine Idee, *was heute Abend betrifft*.

http://www.dict.cc/german-english/was+++betrifft++anbetrifft.html

*"was X betrifft"* is a very common phrase in German. You usually don't say *"Idee über etwas"* in this context.

> Kann ich bitte noch mal fragen für deine Empfehlung?

This looks like a copy of English *"to ask for"*. In German, we say *um etwas bitten* or *nach etwas fragen*. Thus:

> Kann ich bitte noch mal nach deiner Empfehlung fragen?

or

> Kann ich dich bitte noch mal um eine Empfehlung bitten?

The last sentence should be

> Ich möchte etwas **unternehmen, was viel Spaß macht**, aber nicht *<s>bis</s>* zu spät, und <s>*mit*</s> nicht zu viel trinken, weil <s>*Morgen*</s> **morgen** <s>*ist*</s> <s>*meinen letzten*</s> **mein letzter** Tag hier **ist**.

Note, after *weil* we put the verb at the end of the sentence. And the word *Morgen* means *morning*, but *morgen* is *tomorrow*. Side note: "tomorrow morning" is in German not <s>morgen Morgen</s> but *morgen früh*.

I hope it helped.